# How could I render GIF image twice with different frame index offset?

Tags: java, animation, desktop-application, gif

### Explanation:

I am working on simple desktop game in Java using `.gif` animations as graphics. I created animations for units' actions for every type (move up / down / left / right, stad, dying, etc.).

Loading gif image with resource name (path example: `"images/player_stand.gif"`):

```
public Image loadImageResource(String path) {
    Image image = null;
    URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path);
    if (url != null) {
        image = new ImageIcon(url).getImage();
    } else {
        System.err.println("Can't load resource file: " + path);
    }
    return image;
}
```

I render gif image animation like this (simplified):

```
public class ImageComponent extends JComponent implements ImageObserver {

    private Image _image;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        if (_image != null) {
            g2.drawImage(_image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean imageUpdate(Image img, int infoflags, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        return super.imageUpdate(img, infoflags, x, y, w, h);
    }
}
```

I can reset gif animation like this:

```
image.flush();
```

Everything works.

---

### Problem:

I **load** animation **image only once** *(I couldn't load image twice, it's the same instance)*, so I use the same image for every player's action. I would like to render animation but starting from different frame index, so one player's dying animation is in the middle of progress and other just started dying.

- How to control which frame of `.gif` image to render?
- How to reset animation for "`ImageObserver`", just for one `JComponent` object?
- How to simply copy image instance so every animation can own different
  animation data?

What is the best way to reach this solution?

Thank you!